# How to specify workflow should use current version, and n previous versions in github actions?

Tags: devops, github-actions, workflow

I am running some workflows using github actions, that requires using node. Instead of having to hardcode the numeric versions I want to include in the matrix, I would prefer if I could specify something like, use the latest version and 3 previous versions.

This ensures I do not need to update the version matrix with new releases and I can confirm to the requirement to always support the current version and 3 previous versions before that.

But could not find a way to specify the version this way. Any idea if this is possible? If so, how?